# Getting java.io.IOException: Stream Closed from DownloadStream

Tags: java, vaadin, ioexception, vaadin7

I'm currently developing a Vaadin application. The function I'm working on is creating two PDF's, merging them and then downloading it to the client as a temporary file. Just a few times i get this strange IOException with no reference to my code. Any idea on what may cause it?

The stack trace:

```
java.io.IOException: Stream Closed
    at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at com.vaadin.server.DownloadStream.writeResponse(DownloadStream.java:304)
    at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.handleConnectorRequest(AbstractClientConnector.java:646)
    at com.vaadin.server.ConnectorResourceHandler.handleRequest(ConnectorResourceHandler.java:83)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1408)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:350)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Any idea on what may cause it?

`java.io.IOException: stream closed` is caused by closing the stream and then continuing to use it. It is a bug in your code.

NB It is *not* caused by anything the peer does, and specifically not caused by the peer closing *his* end of the connection.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! That's how far I've got too. The strange thing is that I never get the error when u run this application on my local computer. I have a server where 50 users or so are online. Is there some way I can create this error on my local test-server to get a better understanding on my streams?

Comment: You can create the error by doing what I said above, but I fail to see the point. What you have to do is *fix* it, i.e. find the path that closed the stream before the exception was thrown.

Comment: Any thoughts on why this error don't show regularly? It just sometimes pop up.

Comment: Err, the code path concerned is only sometimes executed? Have you considered investigating it?

Comment: Thanks again for the fast reply! I will try to investigate the code.